# Applescript's System Events forces Mac OS Roman encoding?

Tags: unicode, utf-8, character-encoding, applescript, mac-roman

I have written an Applescript which reads the first line of a UTF-8 text file. That string is used to "set value" a particular text area of an IRC client (Textual).

Unfortunately, any characters not native to Mac OS Roman encoding (unicode-only characters, asian-only glyphs) are substituted for Mac OS Roman characters.

For example:

- 旦 welcome

is written into the text area as:

- Êó¶ welcome

**How can I force the text back into UTF-8 encoding, or fix this issue?**

*my script:*

```
set source to "/Users/admin/Documents/file.txt" --UTF-8 file
set N to paragraphs of (read POSIX file source)
set phrase to first item of N

tell application "Textual" --IRC client
activate
tell application "System Events"
    delay 0.3
    set value of text area 1 of scroll area 1 of window 1 of process "Textual" to phrase
    --the main text entry field of this application
    keystroke return
end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
set N to paragraphs of (read POSIX file source as «class utf8»)
```

Comment: awesome! thank you, I was missing as «class utf8» both in the read and write portions of my code